# MySQL CHECK constraint alternative

Tags: mysql, constraints

As per the MySQL manual "The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines."  So I know the simple solution is out of the question but is there another feasible means of coming to the same outcome?  Maybe through some use of triggers or stored procedures?  If so how?

Also since it is just "parsed" is that as good as saying avoid using it since it doesn't serve a purpose?

Using MySQL 5.5.11 and InnoDB tables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this interesting article

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Triggers#Triggers-EmulatingCheckConstraints

I often use that method.

Comment: Great thanks for that link.  Gives good detail on how to implement it.  I will have to play with it a bit and see if the limitations raise problems in my app.  Do you really use a dedicated db just for these triggers?

Comment: Hi. I don't understand what you mean with dedicated db. I use triggers every time I need them in all the dbs that require them.

Comment: Taken from that tutorial "To do this we need to create two things, a table to produce the error against and a procedure to insert into that table which will in turn raise an error. It would be a good idea to create these in a separate database so that they can be accessed by any database."

Comment: Ah, ok. To be sincere I use them within each single db. Let's see if someone else has some good advice. :)

Comment: The link unfortunately leads to a page without content :/

Answer (score 2):

I am using version 5.5.21
you can use ENUM for check constraints
 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: Not very useful on a `FLOAT` column, or where the allowed values are something like 0-100000...