# MySQL can I use regex to denote the type of a row?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have a 'User' table with a column:

```
USERNAME varchar(40)
```

A 'User' can either be a management user, or a standard user.  Management users always contain purely numeric usernames.

I can then use regex to pull out all the users with numeric names to get the management users, and vice versa to get the non management.

Is it okay practice to therefore use regex in my select queries to get this information, or should I instead add an additional column:

```
MANAGEMENT TINYINT(1)
```

Which stores whether a user is a management user or not.

What is best practice and why?

Comment: add something like role in User table. and keep management, standard etc in role table. have the role id IN user table.

Answer (score 3):

It is *really* not very safe or efficient to rely on this sort of "hidden" meaning in a field. Add a new field. Really. There is *no* sensible reason not to.

I would also recommend reading this article on [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Some examples:

> 9: People’s names are written in ASCII.
>
> 15: People’s names do not contain numbers.
>
> 24: My system will never have to deal with names from China.
>
> 25: Or Japan.
>
> 26: Or Korea.

Can your regex handle all of those? For sure? Every time?

Answer (score 2):

It is generally preferable to design the schema to be [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).  This includes not having multiple columns that would store the same information.  However, the username and being a management user are definitely distict information and you need both.

You can use the `BIT` type for the new column.

In case you want to enforce particular formats of user name, the standard database solution would be to define a check constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT YourConstraint CHECK ( is_management_user = 0 OR ...)
```

(where the `...` would include `REGEXP_LIKE` on Oracle, cast to an integer in TSQL or something like that).

However, MySql [does not enforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807231/mysql-check-constraint-alternative) check constraints and you have to emulate them using triggers if you consider the form of the `USERNAME` somehow important for security or operation of your application - which, I would hope, it really isn't.