# why zero not going to database when its type integer?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

can I know why it is not inserting zero to my database when its type in integer. I have a table called contact and there is a column to keep users' 10 digits length mobile no. This number generally start with 0. Eg. 0713423454, 0234324545 etc.

In my table I have create that column like this..

```
mobile INT(10) NOT NULL,
```

In php I validate it something like this...

```
// Check for a mobile number:
if ( !empty($_POST['mobile'])) {
    $number = $_POST['mobile'];     
    if (preg_match('/(0[0-9]{9})/', $number)) {
        $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $dbc, $number);
    } else {
        $reg_errors['mobile'] = 'You are NOT entered valid Mobile number!';
    }
} else {    
    $reg_errors['mobile'] = 'Mobile number can not be empty!';
}
```

But when inserting mobile number to database its going without 0 like this 234223434, 435453545 etc.

So I would like to know is there a way to insert my mobile number with 0 to database..

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers do not (cannot) have leading zeros. That is, both '099' and '99' represent the same numeric value<sup>1</sup>.

Use a [char or varchar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> Sometimes a leading zero in the text-representation of a number specifies the [octal] base, but that is *not* the case here.

Comment: If mobile number contain characters will this clause a problem with char or varchar?

Comment: @TharangaNuwan Check Constraints (not in MySQL), Triggers, and/or a strict DAL (not in DB). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807231/mysql-check-constraint-alternative

Answer (score 4):

You cannot store leading zeros, but your larger problem is that you should not store a mobile number as INT.  Store it as CHAR.

Mobile numbers are identifiers, not numeric values.  You'll save yourself a lot of grief if you alter your data model.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`zerofill`](http://hashmysql.org/wiki/Zerofill) for your column..

Comment: can you explain this with an example?

Comment: The link i provided has one and an explanation

Comment: You can't really expect zerofill to have a meaningful effect on phone numbers, can you? 0 preceding a phone number does not equal no digit at all. It's a switching command! You should accept what @pst posted as an answer to your question.